# iOS Amplify queries only work after second time view controller appears

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I'm running Amplify queries as soon as my view controller loads, however no data is returned unless I switch to another tab and then go back, or reload the app then it works. It then works every time after that every time the view controller is loaded it's just not working the very first time. This is on multiple real devices and simulator. Can someone tell me why it doesn't work the first time but every other time afterwards?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        inspections = [InspectionWrapper]()
        fetchInspectionData()
}

func fetchInspectionData() {
    let amplify = AmplifyHelper()
    
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    
    
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        amplify.queryInspections { retrievedInspections in
            for inspection in retrievedInspections {
       
                var newInspection = InspectionWrapper(inspection: inspection)
                
                amplify.queryInspectionResponses(forInspection: inspection) { retrievedInspectionReponses in
                    for inspectionReponse in retrievedInspectionReponses {
                        
                        newInspection.inspectionResponses.append(inspectionReponse)

                        amplify.queryQuestions(forInspectionResponse: inspectionReponse) { retrievedQuestions in
                            for question in retrievedQuestions {
                                
                                var questionAndAnswers = QuestionAndAnswers(question: question, answers: nil)
                                
                                amplify.queryAnswers(forQuestion: question) { retrievedAnswers in
                                    questionAndAnswers.answers = [Answer]()
                                    for answer in retrievedAnswers {
                                        questionAndAnswers.answers?.append(answer)
                                    }
                                    
                                    newInspection.questionAndAnswers.append(questionAndAnswers)
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.inspections.append(newInspection)
                }
                
            }
            
  
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

AmplifyHelper()

```
func queryInspections(completion: @escaping ([Inspection]) -> ())  {
        Amplify.DataStore.query(Inspection.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let retrievedInspections):
                completion(retrievedInspections)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error on query for type Inspection - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func queryInspectionResponses(forInspection inspection: Inspection, completion: @escaping ([InspectionResponse]) -> ()) {
        let inspectionResponseKeys = InspectionResponse.keys
        Amplify.DataStore.query(InspectionResponse.self, where: inspectionResponseKeys.inspectionID.eq(inspection.id)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let retrievedInspectionResponses):
                completion(retrievedInspectionResponses)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error on query for type InspectionResponse - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func queryQuestions(forInspectionResponse inspectionResponse: InspectionResponse, completion: @escaping ([Question]) -> ()) {
        let questionKeys = Question.keys
        Amplify.DataStore.query(Question.self, where: questionKeys.inspectionID.eq(inspectionResponse.inspectionID)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let retrievedQuestions):
                completion(retrievedQuestions)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error on query for type Question - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func queryAnswers(forQuestion question: Question, completion: @escaping ([Answer]) -> ()) {
        let answerKeys = Answer.keys
        Amplify.DataStore.query(Answer.self, where: answerKeys.qid.eq(question.id)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let retrievedAnswers):
                completion(retrievedAnswers)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error on query for type Answer - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your collection view loading data from? self.inspections? You may have a race condition....Try moving

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

One bracket up so that it executes only after amplify.queryInspections has completed. Caching is probably what's allowing subsequent queries to complete before reloadData is called.